# How to get the exception shown in WinDBG via CLRMD

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, clrmd

When i open a crash dump (mini dump) via WinDBG it usually points to a particular call stack and exception. Likewise when i open it in Visual Studio (it also automatically selects the correct thread where the exception originated). In CLRMD i can inspect each thread's stack trace/exception but how do i know which thread was active at the time/what was the last exception to occur?

Comment: Maybe `.ecxr` and `.exr` can help. I had some scenarios where WinDbg didn't set the correct context automatically. That could be resolved with these commands. Unfortunately, I don't know how to apply this to CLRMD.

Comment: Afaik, you can't find in the dump answer to the question "which thread was active at the time/what was the last exception to occur". But you can find information about what thread was active at the moment when dump was created (in WinDbg it's ~ and thread marked with . at the beginning).

Comment: Then a question of when the dump was created comes to the scene. If it was created on first chance exception then most probably the active thread is the thread that threw an exception and triggered debugger to generate the dump.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in ClrMD.